# Find an upper bound on $u(t)$ given differential inequality $u'\le au$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a$ and $b$ be a positive constants, and let $u(t)$ be a differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying the inequality $u'(t) \le au(t), u(0)\le b$. Find an upper bound on u(t) and prove that it is the best possible.

I tried to solve this problem by expanding the $u(t)$ and get $$u(t) = u(0) + u'(0)t + O(t^2)\le b + ab + O(t^2)$$ 
I'm not sure about whether the upper bound is $b + ab$ or not.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting problem. I think for a start it might be worth considering whether $a < 1$ or not.

Comment: Hint: You might consider $u'(t) = au(t) - f(t)$ as a linear ODE, where $f(t)$ is a nonnegative function.

Comment: The upper bound is b exp (at) , the function starts with b at max and grows exponentially at max...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $v(t)=e^{-at}u(t)$, which satisfies
$$
v'(t) = -ae^{-at}u(t)+ e^{-at}u'(t)\le 0
$$
and therefore $v(t)\le v(0)$.

The equality case is attained when $v$ is constant.

Comment: Nice solution.  I guess this mimics a standard proof for linear inhomogeneous ODEs, but eliminates the step of solving which is not needed here.

Comment: Actually, I don't get it... I don't know why you set up the function $v(t)$?